# Token in Android usefull?

Tags: java, android

I am currently developing an android app with a friend. We'll have a login system in the app. As we both coded in asp net we used authentication token. But I was wondering if we also had to use it for an android app, we're both beginner in that and we don't really now.
We're going to use an API for authentication system. And we don't know if we have to use a token system to check every time if the user is logged and can execute the request, or if we just ask the user to authenticate once and store login in phone(even if it seems weird to do that).

Comment: You only store the token in the device not the login information. Therefore it is not necessary to ask for login information again unless the Token is flagged as expired.

Comment: Thank you for the answer solved my thoughts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> And we don't know if we have to use a token system to check every time if the user is logged and can execute the request

The first time the user authenticates, you can give him a user token for that session, and store it in the [Shared Preferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

Then, if you a library such as [Retrofit](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-token-authentication-on-android) you can send the user authentication token in each API call as a header.

Comment: Thank you, for your answered helped me to understand